# Given a set of points calculate the outline of the area that the points cover

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

I want to find the outline polygon representation of an area covered by points, so lets say that I have a list of points that look like the following image:

[image]

I want to be able to get the polygon coordinates of the boundaries covered by the points preferebly with a set distance from the most outer points:

[image]

the polygon coordinates retrieved should represent a shape that looks like the following image:
[image]

is there an standard algorithm already out there for this kind of computation?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Actually, that's an alpha shape with a buffer, not a convex hull.  The convex hull is *convex*, not *concave* (as shown in the diagram).

Answer (score 1):

The shape you are describing is an alpha shape (with a buffer added after computation), with the algorithm [described in this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1056714).

[Hull](http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/hull.html) provides an implementation (when used with `-aa`) of this in C, and CGAL includes an  open source implementation of [alpha shapes](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html) in C++.  The CGAL documentation describes the basic algorithm, which requires computing the delaunay triangulation of the input points, then using a defined radius to "carve away" the outside.